# Help to translate a Prayer into Hebrew

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, transliteration

I am learning Hebrew and I have this prayer which I want to pray:

Yehi ratzon milfanecha, shetimaleh retzon'cha, v'lo retzoni, v'she'ehye merkava lirtzonecha. 
Bifratus, avakesh mimcha emunah ubitachon bicha. 
Ve'ein safek she'biyadcha li'azreini.

I know the meaning of the prayer, but I would like also to know how to write it in Hebrew to understand better. Can you please rewrite in hebrew? Thank you for your service.

Comment: Frankly, in Hebrew, it sounds a bit awkward. "יהי רצון שתמלא רצונך" sounds weird. WHy בפרטות? What do you think " ושאהיה מרכבה לרצונך" means? When you plan to use it and how often?

Comment: Hebrew does not have all words of my language, so this is expression of "Let your will happen, not mine, but yours. You act in me all the will and acts according to your will." In fact, this is also translated from my native language, so it is translated twice. In my native language I add "In particular..." when I add significance to something which is very important. So while the first part of the prayer is general, the second part specifies my needs. As I see the *bitachon* to be very important. If I can remember the words, I want to pray it every day.

Comment: I would recommend two things: 1. Check for an existing formulation - there'are lots of books of prayers and makings. 2. Say it in יהי רצון in שמע קולנו when davening the regular silent Amidah, and not as a stand-alone prayer.

Comment: "In particular" should be translated as בפרט (bifrat) or במיוחד (bimyuchad). "Bifratus" is not a meaningful word on Hebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> יהי רצון מלפניך,‏
>
> שתמלא רצונך ולא רצוני, ושאהיה מרכבה לרצונך.‏
>
> בפרטות, אבקש ממך אמונה ובטחון בך.‏
>
> ואין ספק שבידך לעזרני.‏